# Fill textboxes with null values

Tags: java, jdbc, dao

I'm writing a Webapp where there is data that has to be pulled from database and displayed in textboxes. Everything is working fine. But I need to display the value as `No Data Available` in those textboxes `if(!rs.next())`, currently I'm trying the below code.

```
package org.DAO;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.bean.UserBean;
import org.code.general.DBConnection;
import org.code.general.GetTheUserDetails;

public class GetDataDAO {
    DBConnection dbConnection = new DBConnection();
    GetTheUserDetails getTheUserDetails = new GetTheUserDetails();

    public List<UserBean> list(String systemUserName) throws Exception {

        List<UserBean> userBeans = new ArrayList<UserBean>();
        try {

            Connection conn = dbConnection.getConn();
            Statement stmt = dbConnection.getStmt();
            ResultSet rs = dbConnection.getRs();
            String excelPath = dbConnection.getExcelPath();
            String queryString = null;
            dbConnection.createClassForNameForExcel();
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};DBQ=" + excelPath + "; READONLY=FALSE;");
            System.out.println("Connecting to database…");
            System.out.println("Oracle JDBC Driver Registered!");
            if (conn != null) {
                System.out.println("You made it, take control your database now!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Failed to make connection!");
            }
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            queryString = "Select * from [" + dbConnection.getSheetPath()
                    + "$] where STATE IS NULL and [Case Owner] = '"
                    + getTheUserDetails.getUserNameDetails(systemUserName) + "'";
            System.out.println("Query is " + queryString);
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(queryString);
            ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
            System.out.println("bno of cols are " + rsmd.getColumnCount());
            while (rs.next()) {
                if (rs.next()) {
                    UserBean userBean = new UserBean();
                    userBean.setCaseNumber(rs.getString(1));
                    userBean.setCaseOwner(rs.getString(2));
                    userBean.setStatus(rs.getString(4));
                    userBean.setIssue(rs.getString(5));
                    userBean.setReason(rs.getString(6));
                    userBean.setDateOpened(rs.getString(7));
                    userBean.setAge(rs.getInt(8));
                    userBeans.add(userBean);
                } else {
                    UserBean userBean = new UserBean();
                    userBean.setCaseNumber("None");
                    userBean.setCaseOwner("None");
                    userBean.setStatus("None");
                    userBean.setIssue("None");
                    userBean.setReason("None");
                    userBean.setDateOpened("None");
                    userBean.setAge(Integer.parseInt("None"));
                    userBeans.add(userBean);
                }
            }

            rs.close();
            conn.commit();
            conn.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return userBeans;
    }
}
```

As per my understanding, I've written trying the below algorithm,

```
if(rs.next)
   then create the bean and add the values from database,
 else 
   create the bean and add the values as None
```

please let me know where am I going wrong and how can I fix this.

Thanks

Comment: I do not think it is a great idea to call the `rs.next()` twice. This will result in not showing the first value, because you skipped it. And second, if the database does not contain any values, then it should not point to a new row. Are you saying the values are just null, but the row is present? I am just afraid that the rows would be empty, and then you logic inside the loop will not work.

Comment: Also, if the `rs.next()` is false, this means you can not create an empty UsesrBean. You would have to do that outside of the while loop.

Comment: Hi @JernejK, sould i remove `while(rs.next())` and keep the `if-else`?

Comment: It depends. Does the database returns an instance, just that all the rows are null? Or does that mean the table does not contain rows at all? Because if the table does not contain any rows, then the `rs.next()' method will be always false. And you if else will not even get executed, because it will already fail to even get inside the while loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(rs.next)
   then create the bean and add the values from database,
 else 
     set the bean as null
```

In jsp check if bean is null then `No Data Available` under text boxes. Ideally you should do it in servlet or controller as jsp should be as light as it can be

Answer (score 1):

The code is skipping a row per iteration:

```
while (rs.next()) {
    if (rs.next())
```

If the result set is either 0 or 1 row then just use `rs.next()`:

```
if (rs.next())
{
    // Use 'rs'.
}
else
{
    // "None".
}
```

Additionally:

- the `null` check on `conn` is superfluous as [`DriverManager.getConnection()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#getConnection-java.lang.String-) throws an exception if it fails.
- use try-with-resources to ensure `Connection`, `Statement` and `ResultSet` are always released.

Answer (score 1):

**public boolean next()**

Moves the cursor to the next row. This method returns false if there are no more rows in the result set.

So when you call `rs.next()` twice, once in `while` and once in `if` , you will miss one row every time.

Try remove `if` condition

Answer (score 1):

You would have to have logic like this, if the rows are empty:

```
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(queryString);
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();

        System.out.println("bno of cols are " + rsmd.getColumnCount());

        while (rs.next()) {
                UserBean userBean = new UserBean();
                userBean.setCaseNumber(rs.getString(1));
                userBean.setCaseOwner(rs.getString(2));
                userBean.setStatus(rs.getString(4));
                userBean.setIssue(rs.getString(5));
                userBean.setReason(rs.getString(6));
                userBean.setDateOpened(rs.getString(7));
                userBean.setAge(rs.getInt(8));
                userBeans.add(userBean);
        }
        if(userBeans.size() == 0) {
                UserBean userBean = new UserBean();
                userBean.setCaseNumber("None");
                userBean.setCaseOwner("None");
                userBean.setStatus("None");
                userBean.setIssue("None");
                userBean.setReason("None");
                userBean.setDateOpened("None");
                userBean.setAge(Integer.parseInt("None"));
                userBeans.add(userBean);
        }

        rs.close();
        conn.commit();
        conn.close();
```

But if the rows are not empty, just containing null values, then you can have the logic like this:

```
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(queryString);
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
        System.out.println("bno of cols are " + rsmd.getColumnCount());

        while (rs.next()) {
                UserBean userBean = new UserBean();
                String value = rs.getString(1) == null ? "None" : rs.getString(1);
                // you do this for all the columns, from 1 to 8
                userBean.setCaseNumber(rs.getString(1));
                userBean.setCaseOwner(rs.getString(2));
                userBean.setStatus(rs.getString(4));
                userBean.setIssue(rs.getString(5));
                userBean.setReason(rs.getString(6));
                userBean.setDateOpened(rs.getString(7));
                userBean.setAge(rs.getInt(8));
                userBeans.add(userBean);
        }

        rs.close();
        conn.commit();
        conn.close();
```

Comment: Glad my first code did help you out. Have fun coding more :)